# Optimising SQL query to find duplicates in a table with large amounts of data

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I have the following table on SQL Server 2014:

```
id          field1         field2
----------- ---------------------------------
1           1                 a
2           2                 a
3           3                 a
4           3                 b
5           4                 a
6           5                 a
7           6                 b
8           1                 a
9           2                 a
10          3                 c
11          4                 b
12          4                 c
13          5                 b
```

Now I want to find records where duplicate values in field1 are listed when they have different values for field 2, and currently I'm using the following query to do so:

```
;with tmp_cte as (
select field1,field2 from mytable (nolock)
group by field1,field2)

select * from tmp_cte cte1
where (select count(field2) from tmp_cte cte2 where cte1.field1=cte2.field1)>1
```

This is the outcome:

```
field1       field2
-------------------------------
3               a
3               b
3               c
4               a
4               b
4               c
5               a
5               b
```

Now although this works, it is incredibly slow on a table with large amounts of data (160 million records),  so I want to optimize the query since it currently takes longer than 1hr on just 1 month of data (+-10 million records)
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever heard about `Indexes` https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190263/Indexes-in-MS-SQL-Server  in SQL Server?

Comment: Sure I have, but indexes aren't helping me here. The above are only examples, but my actual table is more complex and the text fields aren't indexed (Not my design, but my problem). I'm sure there's a far more efficient method of achieving the same result and that's why I'm here, with all my hope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
        declare @t table(id int,field1 int,field2 varchar(10))
        insert into @t VALUES
        (1  ,1,  'a'),(2  ,2,  'a'),(3  ,3,  'a')
        ,(4  ,3,  'b'),(5  ,4,  'a'),(6  ,5,  'a')
        ,(7  ,6,  'b'),(8  ,1,  'a'),(9  ,2,  'a')
        ,(10 ,3,  'c'),(11 ,4,  'b'),(12 ,4,  'c')
        ,(13 ,5,  'b')

        ;with CTE as
(
select * 
,DENSE_RANK()over(partition by field1 order by field2)rn

from @t
)


select * from cte c
where  EXISTS(select id from cte c1 where 
c.field1=c1.field1 and c1.rn>1 )
```

Comment: This one worked and the speed was much better than my initial query. The only addition needed was field grouping but I added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select distinct
    t.field1,
    t.field2 
from
    mytable t
    join
    (select 
        field1
    from 
        mytable
    group by 
        field1
    having
        count(field2) > 1) sub
    on t.field1 = sub.field1
order by
    field1
```

Comment: This query also includes the records that do not have multiple values on `field2` where `field1` has the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
Select field1,field2 from mytable (nolock) where field1 in
    (Select field1 from mytable (nolock) group by field1 having count(field1)>1)
```

Comment: This query also includes records where there aren't multiple values for field2 where field1 is duplicated

Answer (score 0):

[<kbd>DEMO HERE</kbd>](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/674771)

```
 ;with cte
    as
    (select field1,field2,
    count(  field1) over(partition by field1 order by field2) as cnt,
    dense_rank() over(partition by field1 order by field2) as drnk
     from #temp
    )
    select * from cte where cnt-drnk=0
```

With below index on table,this query can run fast

```
create index nci on table(field1,field2)
```